# UPDATE rows that exist, INSERT rows that do not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Users and UserMap. I need something like this...

```
INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ID, VALUE_TYPE, SOME_VALUE)
SELECT USERS.ID, 0, 1
```

The problem is that I would like to update rather than insert if the user and type already exists. This is my solution.

```
DELETE FROM USERS
WHERE USERS.VALUE_TYPE = 0

INSERT INTO USERS (USER_ID, VALUE_TYPE, SOME_VALUE)
SELECT USERS.ID, 0, 1
FROM USERS
```

This works, I was just looking for something better if it exists. Any recommendations?

Edit. Whoops, I typed this incorrectly. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for all the help.

Comment: So use `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE` (MySQL)?

Comment: It is possible in some databases, so which database are you using?

Comment: @njk that would depend entirely on *which* database (s)he's using

Comment: Oracle has a merge statement http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Comment: @crowne MSSQL also has `MERGE` functionality

Comment: Well, SQL-92 way to "merge" 2 relations `users` and `newusers` that should work for all database systems: you can use except (something like `newusers except users`) to find the truly new users and insert them. For all others you can do an update.

Comment: Is SOME_VALUE supposed to be hard-coded to 1 for all users, or should this value actually come from the UserMap table? Also is the ID column USER_ID or ID? It should be called the same thing throughout the model to eliminate that kind of confusion.

Comment: Why are you deleting all the records `WHERE USERS.VALUE_TYPE = 0` to insert a single record? Which filed(s) you need to check for existence and update?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 - MERGE (Transact-SQL): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx
  Some example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Answer (score 4):

What you're currently doing is very expensive. What if you have a million rows and only four rows have changed? What if no rows have changed?

The typical model is something like:

```
-- first, update the rows that match
UPDATE u
  SET SOME_VALUE = m.SOME_VALUE
  FROM dbo.Users AS u
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserMap AS m
  ON u.ID = m.USER_ID
  AND u.VALUE_TYPE = m.VALUE_TYPE
  WHERE u.VALUE_TYPE = 0;

-- next, add the rows that don't match
INSERT dbo.Users(USER_ID, VALUE_TYPE, SOME_VALUE)
  SELECT m.USER_ID, 0, 1
  FROM dbo.UserMap AS m
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Users
      WHERE ID = m.USER_ID
      AND VALUE_TYPE = 0
  );
```

You can also use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) but personally I find the syntax quite daunting. Also, I'm not sure I trust that [all of the bugs that have been reported against it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&sclient=psy-ab&q=merge%20bug%20site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=4a19662fa4882be9&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.dmQ&biw=2141&bih=1421) have been resolved. ([Different link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=merge%2bbug).)

Comment: It does work, but on a personnal note, I sometimes prefer to delete and insert, when the query takes too much time to run because of the complexity. (So I'd rather make the DELETE, then run the complexe query once to INSERT, rather than to run it twice to make an INSERT + UPDATE)

Comment: @Danielle [There are better solutions to that, too](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo).

Comment: I know but I work on a very old system (dates back to OS/2 with Betrieve) and sometimes, they don't want to change ANYTHING because they are scared to do any changes... Wich means that I have to find ways to improve performances without adding indexes, or without touching to the DB structure in any way, or sometimes, I can't even change the query because they are scared that it will change the result. You can try to explain some things to them, but sometimes, it's useless... The kind of things that would go on http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: In a day-to-day basis, I do a lot of query optimisation, and DB optimisation. But for some features of the application, they just won't let you touch anything because nobody really knows how it works and they are too scared to touch it. (It's slow, customers are complaining, but it works, so why touch it right?) After trying to change it, after a few years, I just decided to choose the battles I fight

Comment: @Danielle that's ok, but just because someone is using an inefficient process because they're scared to change it, doesn't mean you should ever *prefer* that method (which is what your original comment stated).

Comment: Sorry, I'm french, so maybe I didn't express myself correctly ;-)